# How to fire one publisher after another?

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I have two publishers, one that gathers messages based on a state, and the second which is a Timer. I want these to fire in order - so first gather data, then start a timer. How can I do this? This is my current code:

```
let messagesPublisher = OnboardingStateLogic.publisher(
  forState: state,
  nextState: nextState
)

messagesPublisher
  .sink { completion in 
    print("completed")
  } receiveValue: { [weak self] messages in
    messages.forEach { message in
      self?.queue.enqueue(message)
    }
  }

timer = Timer
  .publish(every: 2, on: .main, in: .default)
  .autoconnect()
  .sink { _ in
    self.dequeueMessages()
  }
```

Comment: Did my response answer your question?

Comment: @jnpdx I ended up going with Zip

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up using `Publishers.Zip`. This only publishes when both upstream publishers have outputted a value:

```
messagesPublisher.sink(
  receiveCompletion: { _ in },
  receiveValue: { [weak self] message in
   self?.queue.enqueue(message)
  }
).store(in: &cancellables)

let delayPublisher = Timer
  .publish(every: 2, on: .main, in: .default)
  .autoconnect()
  .eraseToAnyPublisher()
  .setFailureType(to: Error.self)

let delayedValuesPublisher = Publishers.Zip(messagesPublisher, delayPublisher).eraseToAnyPublisher()

delayedValuesPublisher.sink(
  receiveCompletion: { completion in
    switch completion {
    case .failure(let error):
      print("something went wrong", error)
    case .finished:
      break
    }
  },
  receiveValue: { [weak self] _ in
    self?.dequeueMessages()
  }
).store(in: &cancellables)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `flatMap` operator to transform a publisher or value into a new publisher in the Combine chain. For example:

```
class ViewModel : ObservableObject {
    var cancellable : AnyCancellable?
    
    init() {
        cancellable = Just(1).flatMap { _ in
            Timer
              .publish(every: 2, on: .main, in: .default)
              .autoconnect()
        }.sink { value in
            print("Publisher fired: \(value)")
        }
    }
}
```

You would replace my trivial `Just(1)` publisher with your `messagesPublisher`